# Using kenai plugin for netbeans which operates the Google application engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, netbeans, netbeans-6.9

1. using NetBeans 6.9.1

   1. using Google App Engine plugin for NetBeans from [Kenai](http://kenai.com/projects/nbappengine/pages/Home)
   2. I did exactly the same as shown on this video tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kAhaDNs87sc

For some reason after I hit the deploy to google app engine I get a very long exception:
  (this view is not the full text of this error..)

Why is it happening?

```
Reading application configuration data...
29/04/2011 00:57:59 com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader readAppEngineWebXml
INFO: Successfully processed C:/Users//Documents/NetBeansProjects/applet-example/build/web\WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
29/04/2011 00:57:59 com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlReader readConfigXml
INFO: Successfully processed C:/Users//Documents/NetBeansProjects/applet-example/build/web\WEB-INF/web.xml
Beginning server interaction for applet-example...
0% Creating staging directory
5% Scanning for jsp files.
8% Compiling jsp files.

Error Details:
29/04/2011 00:58:00 org.apache.jasper.compiler.AntCompiler generateClass
SEVERE: Error compiling file: C:\Users\4EBE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg75983006369417083.tmp\WEB-INF\classes\org\apache\jsp\index_jsp.java     [javac] Compiling 1 source file

29/04/2011 00:58:00 org.apache.jasper.compiler.AntCompiler generateClass
SEVERE: Javac exception
Error running javac.exe compiler
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.compilers.DefaultCompilerAdapter.executeExternalCompile(DefaultCompilerAdapter.java:473)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.compilers.JavacExternal.execute(JavacExternal.java:47)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.compile(Javac.java:931)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.execute(Javac.java:757)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.AntCompiler.generateClass(AntCompiler.java:226)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:349)
        at org.apache.jasper.JspC.processFile(JspC.java:1192)
        at org.apache.jasper.JspC.execute(JspC.java:1341)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalJspC.main(LocalJspC.java:18)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "javac.exe": CreateProcess error=2, ???????? ??? ?????? ???? ?? ?÷??? ?????
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute$Java13CommandLauncher.exec(Execute.java:834)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.launch(Execute.java:435)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.execute(Execute.java:449)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.compilers.DefaultCompilerAdapter.executeExternalCompile(DefaultCompilerAdapter.java:470)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, ???????? ??? ?????? ???? ?? ?÷??? ?????
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
        ... 18 more
--- Nested Exception ---
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "javac.exe": CreateProcess error=2, ???????? ??? ?????? ???? ?? ?÷??? ?????
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute$Java13CommandLauncher.exec(Execute.java:834)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.launch(Execute.java:435)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.execute(Execute.java:449)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.compilers.DefaultCompilerAdapter.executeExternalCompile(DefaultCompilerAdapter.java:470)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.compilers.JavacExternal.execute(JavacExternal.java:47)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.compile(Javac.java:931)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.execute(Javac.java:757)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.AntCompiler.generateClass(AntCompiler.java:226)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:349)
        at org.apache.jasper.JspC.processFile(JspC.java:1192)
        at org.apache.jasper.JspC.execute(JspC.java:1341)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalJspC.main(LocalJspC.java:18)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, ???????? ??? ?????? ???? ?? ?÷??? ?????
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
        ... 18 more
29/04/2011 00:58:00 org.apache.jasper.compiler.AntCompiler generateClass
SEVERE: Environment: Compile: javaFileName=C:\Users\4EBE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg75983006369417083.tmp\WEB-INF\classes\org\apache\jsp\index_jsp.java
    classpath=/C:/appengine-java-sdk-1.4.3/appengine-java-sdk-1.4.3/lib/impl/appengine-
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

After having a look at their bug tracker, Netbeans 6.9.1 seems to be unsupported.

http://kenai.com/jira/browse/NBAPPENGINE-50